# Using dojo.hitch and closures in an object, in a method of an outer object?

Tags: javascript, dojo, closures

I have an object declared using Dojo like this (the "..." lines indicate where I've omitted code which I think isn't required to understand the problem):

```
dojo.provide('communityWidgetClass');

dojo.declare('communityWidgetClass',null,{
    ...

    postToTVService: function(svcType,postJson) {
        try {
            var svcPath;
            switch (svcType) {
            case this.SVC_REL: svcPath=insightConfig.relPath; break;
            case this.SVC_MSG: svcPath=insightConfig.msgPath; break;
            default: return;
            }

            this.consoleLog('communityWidget.postToTVService postJson',postJson);

            this.startLoadingResults();
            var args={
                url:insightConfig.proxyPath+svcPath,
                postData:postJson,
                handleAs:'json',
                preventCache:true,
                load:function(data){
                    dojo.hitch(this,'xhrLoad',data,svcType);
                },
                error:function(error){
                    dojo.hitch(this,'xhrError',error);
                }
            };
            var deferred=dojo.xhrPost(args);
        } catch(err) {
            this.consoleError('communityWidget.postToTVService',err);
        }
    },

    ...

    xhrError: function(error) {
        this.consoleError('xhrError',error);
    },

    xhrLoad: function(data,svcType) {
        this.consoleLog('xhrLoad svc:'+svcType,data);
        this.endLoadingResults();
    }
});
```

The `dojo.xhrPost` call inside `postToTVService` runs and retrieves the desired data. I can see the request in Firebug's "Net" tab.

The problem is that neither `args.load` or `args.error` ever call the methods they should call.
I think the reason is that `dojo.hitch` is only running after the post request returns, when it should run before in order for `this` to refer to the outer `communityWidgetClass` object.
However, if I call `dojo.hitch` earlier, the `data` and `error` objects (which I need to pass to `xhrLoad` and `xhrError`) don't exist.

I've looked at a few examples of closures, including one I wrote for a simpler case a few months ago, but can't figure out how to apply them to this case.

How do I make it so that `args.load` can pass the `data` (which only exists at the end of the XHR post request) and `svcType` (which only exists before the post request) arguments to the `communityWidgetClass.xhrLoad` method, and similar with `args.error` passing the `error` argument to `communityWidgetClass.xhrError`?

It might be easier to not have `xhrLoad` and `xhrError` methods at all, and just move their bodies inside `args.load` and `args.error`, but those methods will be bigger when finished, and I think they're easier to read and maintain as methods outside the `args` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `hitch` from a scope where `this` has still the expected value, not in the callback where it is already messed up.

```
var args={
    …,
    load: dojo.hitch(this, function(data) {
        // in this function, `this` is bound correctly - so we can call
        this.xhrLoad(data, svcType);
    }),
    // alternatively, just "hitch" the method when the arguments match
    error: dojo.hitch(this,'xhrError');
};
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Two things that hadn't occurred to me: (1) having an inline function as the second argument to `hitch`, instead of specifying a function name and its arguments; (2) in the case of `error`, not having to specify extra arguments to `hitch` if the arguments match.

Comment: One small thing: your answer is missing a closing bracket on line 6 of the code.

Comment: You even could go further if `xhrLoad` did take `svcType` first: `load: dojo.hitch(this, 'xhrLoad', svcType)` where the `data` parameter matches "the rest"